# how to add + symbol to keyboardType in flutter

Tags: keyboard, flutter

hello I use  keyboardType: TextInputType.phone, to show a phone keyboard but I need to add "+" but to do this I need to push Sym to display "+". It's possible to create a custom keyboard with "+" in shortcut ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just by using the `TextInputType.phone` you get the '+' sign under '0' symbol depending on your keyboard.